# Can @link be routed without PK in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to link "/tags/browse" in a viewset but I think the decorator forces "/tags/:id/browse". Here is my viewset:

```
class TagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer

    @link(permission_classes=[])
    def browse(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
        return Response(data)
```

I would like to have the generic CRUD API for Tags, but I'm also adding a special browse that returns some aggregate data. The current @link works, but I have to go to "/tags/1/browse" instead of a generic "/tags/browse". Is there a straightforward way to do the latter here?

(I can make a separate route, but would prefer to have everything encapsulated in this viewset if possible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As of June 2014 that's not currently supported but it has been merged into the (long running) 2.4 branch.
Take a look at these two...

```
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/886
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1047
```

You may be able to pull something similar into your project by duplicating the work in those PRs (or by running against the 2.4 branch rather than from the latest PyPI version)

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for answering. I think I'll just use what I have until 2.4 is released.